# How to do a RequestRefresh for a specific SSAS partition through Microsoft.AnalysisServices in C#

Tags: c#, ssas

I'm familiar with a 'Full' Database Table refresh via the `RefreshType.Full` refresh type using the `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular` namespace:

```
using var server = new Server();
server.Connect("MyConnectionString");
var db = server.Databases.FindByName("MyDatabaseName");
db.Model.Tables["MyTableName"].RequestRefresh(RefreshType.Full);
```

Say for example, the `MyTableName` database table has three partitions (`Partition 1`, `Partition 2`, and `Partition 3`).

If I didn't want to do the full database table refresh, but rather only a single partition within that database table, how would one do this syntactically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first get the [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.table?view=analysisservices-dotnet) object

```
var table = db.Model.Tables["MyTableName"]
```

the table object has the collection of [partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.table.partitions?view=analysisservices-dotnet#microsoft-analysisservices-tabular-table-partitions)

```
var partion = table.Partitions["Partition 2"];
```

the partition object can be "refreshed" using [RequestRefresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.partition.requestrefresh?view=analysisservices-dotnet#microsoft-analysisservices-tabular-partition-requestrefresh(microsoft-analysisservices-tabular-refreshtype)) method

```
partition.RequestRefresh(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.RefreshType.Full);
```

The actual process will happen when the [SaveChanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.model.savechanges?view=analysisservices-dotnet) method is called on the model

```
var result = db.Model.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you do two particular partitions and not just one? Because `table.Partitions["Partition 2", "Partition 3"];` won't work.